# Converting JO-JO tank into liquid fertiliser tank

Tags: fertilizer

I have this idea of creating my own liquid fertiliser from all the bio-waste my house produces.

I want to take a 2250L JoJo tank filled about halfway with water. Then add all the grass clippings to it. All the chicken and dog manure to it and all bio scraps my kitchen may produce. I also want to acquire a wood chipper to convert any twigs and branches the yard produces into sawdust. Which is another good source of biomatter for the tank.

Give the brew a couple of weeks to ferment and then hopefully you have something good to give your plants.

This is in an attempt to recycle waste and reduce the need to buy fertiliser.

Would this brew be something in the line of liquid fertiliser? Also, would spraying your plant with a brew like this actually do something? Im unsure of how effective this may be and whether it will be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Stock advice is that fresh manure should be applied [no closer than 120 days to harvest,](https://extension.umaine.edu/publications/2510e/) or should be composted that long before application, so it's not fresh.

Composted (or not) dog manure is generally considered [inadvisable for application to a food garden](https://greenvillesoilandwater.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/dogwastecomposting-NRCS-guide.pdf) at all, though it can be applied to other types of plants.

As such, a slurry of chicken and dog manure "brewed a couple of weeks" seems highly inadvisable for most garden uses. Without active aeration, it will probably also be fetid, noxious, and generally unpleasant. You can get a suitable air pump and solve that part if you like, but the other problems remain.

A route to "liquid fertilizer" with a bit more likelihood of success and prior experience would be to compost, and then make compost "tea" from the finished compost (but keep the dog compost separate, and use that directly only where  it's appropriate - don't contaminate your tank with it.)

Comment: Can I do this with garden offal minus the poo? Just put all your wood trough the chipper, grass clipping and random bio matter the kitchen produces and some water.